# Cross referencing tables from appendix file in chapter files on memoir class

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I am writing a document and I have split chapters into independent tex files in memoir class. I want to reference tables in the appendix in chapter files but I get this error message:

> You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you
>   have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside
>   \ref{...} is the same as what is written inside \label{...}.

I have ensured that the labels are the same. Whats more confusing is that the first table compiles well and with no error but the rest dont. What could be the problem?

**Adding a MWE**

Here is a snippet of the appendix tex file and the chapter file.

**Table in the Appendix file**

```
\begin{table}[htbp]  
\caption{T-tests: of difference in characteristics I}
\label{ttestsbal1}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2mm}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-2mm}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{l}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Assigned}    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Actual}      \\
\hline
Gender (1=Male)     &    -0.00468       &     (-0.14)&     -0.0398       &     (-0.95)\\
African (1=yes)     &    -0.00313       &     (-0.21)&      0.0135       &      (0.93)\\
Coloured (1=yes)    &     0.00501       &      (0.41)&    -0.00682       &     (-0.50)\\
Indian (1=yes)      &    -0.00348       &     (-0.48)&    -0.00664       &     (-1.32)\\
White (1=yes)       &     0.00161       &      (0.33)&           0       &         (.)\\
English             &    -0.00576       &     (-0.38)&     -0.0167       &     (-1.12)\\
Afrikaans           &  0.00000480       &      (0.00)&     -0.0145       &     (-1.13)\\
IsiZulu             &     -0.0122       &     (-0.41)&     -0.0182       &     (-0.48)\\
IsiXhosa            &      0.0345       &      (1.32)&      0.0534       &      (1.62)\\
Sesotho             &      0.0118       &      (0.60)&     0.00629       &      (0.26)\\
Tshivenda           &    -0.00230       &     (-0.24)&     0.00431       &      (0.30)\\
IsiTsonga           &     -0.0180       &     (-1.30)&     -0.0145       &     (-0.81)\\
SiSwati             &     0.00578       &      (0.52)&    -0.00126       &     (-0.08)\\
Setswana            &     -0.0263       &     (-1.30)&    -0.00925       &     (-0.35)\\
Sepedi              &     0.00326       &      (0.14)&      0.0182       &      (0.61)\\
IsiNdebele          &     0.00739       &      (0.98)&     -0.0117       &     (-1.04)\\
Other               &     0.00185       &      (0.49)&     0.00386       &      (1.08)\\
Married (1=yes)     &    -0.00184       &     (-0.21)&     0.00494       &      (0.62)\\
Living with a Partner (1=yes)&    0.000927       &      (0.13)&     0.00269       &      (0.24)\\
Widow/Widower (1=yes)&     0.00208       &      (0.95)&           0       &         (.)\\
Divorced or Seperated (1=yes)&   -0.000230       &     (-0.07)&    0.000539       &      (0.11)\\
Never Married (1=yes)&   -0.000931       &     (-0.08)&    -0.00817       &     (-0.56)\\
Completed matric (1=yes)&     -0.0167       &     (-0.53)&      0.0385       &      (0.95)\\
Completed some type of tertiary training after matric (1=yes)&     -0.0136       &     (-0.45)&     -0.0534       &     (-1.36)\\
\hline
Observations        &        1012       &            &         610       &            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} \vspace{0.05in}
\begin{enumerate}
%\tiny
\item[] \sym{*} $p<0.01$, \sym{**} $p<0.05$, \sym{***} $p<0.10$. \vspace{-0.05in}
\item[] Std. errors reported in parenthesis, robust to individual clustering. \vspace{-0.05in}
\item[] Difference is control mean minus treatment mean \vspace{-0.05 in}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

I then cross ref in the chapter file using:

```
Table \ref{ttestsbal1} (see the end of this section) gives the statistical differences .....
```

In the main tex file, I use `\input{chapter1}` etc and not `\include{chapter1}`.

Comment: Could you include the snippet that causes your problem? Reproducing the problem and finding out what the problem is will be much easier.

Comment: @MichaelChatiskatzi I agree. I can think of several reasons what the problem might be, but probably not the one that causes the actual problem.

Comment: As you did not yet provide an example which can be used for reproducing the erroneous behavior, I can do a blind guess only: In case you use the `\include`..`\includeonly`-mechanism for selectively including chapter-files for faster compilation while working/writing, make sure to have compiled your document as many times as necessary for the refeences to match out with all files included before starting selective including. This way you make sure that .aux-files exist and contain all referencing-data needed.

Comment: By the way: What kind of workflow do you have in mind when using the phrase "independent tex files"? In which ways are the tex files independent? In case each .tex-file is a compilable document on its own, you might probably be interested in the packages [xr](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr) and/or [xr-hyper](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My workflow is a thesis type where each chapter is  a seperate tex file (hence my "independent" phrase. I probably should have used "seperate" instead.). I commented out the one table that was initially compiling to see if the other tables will compile and hence cross-refs work. True to it, they all compiled. Note that there isnt a problem with the first table that I can pick up.

Comment: I am using the `\input{chapter}` as opposed to `\include{chapter}`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I don't think that using `\input` causes the problems. Still I cannot say more as your snippet  seems okay to me and thus the snippet alone is not something that lets me reproduce the problematic behavior.  Reproducing the problematic behavior would be the 1st step when tracking down things. Perhaps you can create a copy of your set of files for experimenting ...

Comment: ... Perhaps you can create a copy of your set of files for experimenting and removing portions of code until the problematic behavior does not occur any more. Then you know that the likelihood is high that the last things removed somehow cause the problem...

Comment: Another thing that might happen: There are scenarios where although within the `\label`-command and within the referencing-command you type the same referencing-label, LaTeX won't recognize it as the same thing: E.g., when some .tex-input-file is not written in the same input-encoding as the other .tex-input-files while not taking this into account when using the inputenc-package. E.g., when the babel-package is in use and some language is active with the one input-file and another language is active with the other input-file (-> different babel-shorthands etc)...

Comment: Yet another possible cause for the problem: Do you `\input` files whose names contain spaces? If so, make sure that names of the files in question are in quotes. E.g., `\input{"my file.tex"}` instead of `\input{my file.tex}`. Besides this file-names containing consecutive spaces might cause problems as (La)TeX usually collapses consecutive spaces into one space...